# iphone in-app purchase subscriptions products

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

I am making an in-app purchase application for bulk of quizzes. I have all the information, graphics and data set of quizzes on my server. I want user to purchase quizzes with in-app purchase and want to transfer all the related content of purchased item from my server to application.

Now, apple is asking me to submit binary while adding in-app purchase item. Is this compulsory? For all kind of products (Consumable, Nonconsumable & Subscriptions)?

What if I want to manage the contents(graphics, database for that quiz product) of the product on my server not on itunes connect?

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to submit binaries. In fact, it's not even possible. In-app purchases only have a product ID, a description and a price.

Also, be aware that you can't send new application code to the device via your web server. Only data can be sent.

Comment: actually I am not doing the itunes connect thing. My client is doing that. He told me that for approval of in-app purchase item, apple is prompting for binary submission. Can I have your im details, so I can take more help from you?

Comment: Just submit a binary for the app and then reject it yourself. Stupid but you have to do it.

Comment: No you don't have to do that. I've used the in-app purchase sandbox without ever submitting a binary.